# How to run .exe executable file from linux command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, exe, wine

I have one abc.exe executable file in windows. I am able to execute this application using DOS command promt and give some run-time variable to it.

I want to do same in linux system from terminal.

How can I do this??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Windows EXE files usually can't run on Linux. You might be successful with `wine` which emulates MS Windows, though:

```
wine abc.exe
```

What do you mean by a runtime variable? A command line argument, or environment variable?

Comment: ya I want to pass command line argument with abc.exe file.you said that "wine abc.exe id=123 name=gateway" is working?

Answer (score 2):

chorobas answer is correct, Linux cannot directly run .exe files however with third part software like wine, or running a windows vm to execute your file.